# Thought experiment feedback on preventing unnecessary re-renders for react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So while the virtual dom and diffing are what makes React fast compared to manipulating the dom directly, I've read that if you don't modularize your components it will trigger unnecessary renders because it will re-render all parent components that it received its props from even if their UI did not change. This is one of the biggest performance drawbacks of React.

On the very extreme-side, if I design my app so there are no child components and each one maintains its own state, it may side-step this performance issue but it would be almost impossible to maintain.

What if I create some sort of higher-order component (like redux's connect) that would wrap my entire main  component (which holds all my components) and recursively creates a slice of state for every single component that holds only the props it needs? That way it can retain a redux-like singularity principle and code maintainability while avoiding unnecessary re-renders.

I'm thinking it might have to be used in conjunction with redux in order to have access to all of the props at once somewhere, but maybe it can be used without. This way code-splitting and lazy loading the components will be easy to implement (perhaps setting a max number of concurrent server requests to reduce overhead). I would memoize the props to reduce the number of requests as well.

I was thinking of it as a potential idea for side project but I don't know if it is feasible or if it solves the unnecessary rendering problem. I'm thinking of it as some sort of npm library that can be used on top of redux.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding things here. You mentioned `if you don't modularize your components it will trigger unnecessary renders ` and then you mentioned  `if I design my app so there are no child components and each one maintains its own state, it may side-step this performance issue`.
Isn't one saying if we `modularize => high performance` and the other `not modularized(no child components) => high performance` too?